# what is the "System ID" of a LVM volume group

Tags: lvm

On my system, where I use LVM2, I have several volume groups. When I run `sudo vgdisplay`, I see that all of them have an empty `System ID` field. What is that field for? Is that correct to have it empty for a volume group?

For information my system is Linux Fedora 20.

Comment: See the discussion at http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2006-October/msg00091.html.

Comment: @val0x00ff It seems that the `System ID` is not used by LVM2. Is that true?